# jQuery Ajax delete button works but data not deleted in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, button

The button delete is working fine it's just that it says that 'record deleted successfully' but it wasn't deleted at all at the table and database.

Here's my code for delete query

```
<?php require_once('process.php');
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_oda_request WHERE id=".$_GET['id'];
$mysqli->query($sql);
echo 'Record deleted successfully.'; }?>
```

delete button

```
<td><button class='btn btn-danger delete'>Delete</button></td>
```

my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id");
        if(confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'delete_oda_req.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {id: id},
                error: function() {
                  alert('Something is wrong, couldnt delete record');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#" + id).remove();
                    alert("Record delete successfully.");  
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think you dont get the ID correctly in your php function, try to do echo $_GET['id'] and see if you get it

Comment: it's probably a problem with mysql connection.

do you connect with $mysqli ? 

send your connection code with it's username and password removed.

Comment: i tried to echo $_GET['id'] but the message still "Record delete successfully" but it wasn't deleted.

Answer (score -1):

Dump your $_GET variable. Has it an id?

**Note**: You should not add the id to the string. It cause security issues. [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: if id was empty then if would not run and echo wouldn't show up.